# Scrapy: scrape key/value pairs from weird HTML markup

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I need to extract data from webpages looking like the following:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <p><strong>key1</strong>value1</p>
        <p><strong>key2</strong>value2</p>
        <p><strong>key3</strong>value3</p>
        <p><strong>key4</strong>value4</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Getting a JSON file would be superb:

```
{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", "key3":"value3", "key4":"value4"}
```

Because guess what? Sometimes, the webpages look like:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <p><strong>key1</strong>value1</p>
        <p><strong>key3</strong>value3</p>
        <p><strong>key2</strong>value2</p>
        <p><strong>key4</strong>value4</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <p><strong>key1</strong>value1</p>
        <p><strong>key4</strong>value4</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

(Don't ask. I don't know why the didn't serialize their data correctly, or use this ridiculous markup. I just want to grab the data and be done with it.)

I used Scrapy with great success in the past, but only on really small projects with clear markup and well defined classes or IDs. This is obviously harder, and I can't seem to be able to wrap my head around it. The fact that I know next to nothing about Python doesn't help.

I tried things like that, which obviously won't work:

```
def parse(self, response):
        values = response.xpath('//div[2]/p/node()[not(self::strong)]')
        for value in values:
            yield {
                value.xpath('../strong/text()').extract(): value.extract()
            }
```

I tried doing things with indexes, but selectors don't support indexes. I could try to remember my beginner CS classes about functions and the like, but maybe one of you has an idea? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a set-up to test, but I'd try to find the strong element to get the key then use the following sibling axis to get the value following it, rather than the other way round.

```
def parse(self, response):
    keys = response.xpath('//div[2]/p/strong')
    for key in keys:
        yield {
            key.extract(): key.xpath('following-sibling::node()').extract()
        }
```

Comment: It kinda works: the result is very usable. Unless someone has a better answer, this one will do. Thanks!